# Pass class instance without reference

Tags: c#, reference, pass-by-reference, ref

I've this question about pass some instances by ref or not: here is my problem:

**Case 1: simple var like `int`:**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int nTest = 10;

    testInt(nTest);
    MessageBox.Show(nTest.ToString());
    // this message show me 10

    testIntRef(ref nTest);
    MessageBox.Show(nTest.ToString());
    // this message show me 11
}

private void testInt(int nn)
{
    nn++;
}

private void testIntRef(ref int nn)
{
    nn++;
}
```

this is exactly what I think, if I use the ref, the parameter is passed by reference, so if is changed, when I exit from the function, the value is changed...

**Case 2: class:**

```
// simple class to understand the reference..
public class cTest
{
    int nTest;
    public cTest()
    {
        setTest(0);
    }

    public void setTest(int n)
    {
        nTest = n;
    }

    public int getTest()
    {
        return nTest;
    }
}

// my main code
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cTest tt = new cTest();
    tt.setTest(2);

    testClass(tt);

    // I expect that the message shows me 2, 'cause testClass
    // doesn't have (ref cTest test)
    MessageBox.Show(tt.getTest().ToString());
}

private void testClass(cTest test)
{
    test.setTest(55);
}
```

and, as written in the comment on the code, I don't have passed my cTest as reference, but the result is the same, the message show me 55 and not 2..

How can I pass a class without reference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How can I pass a class without reference?

**You can't.**

You can clone that instance and send it, but it will still be sent by ref...

- class - Reference type
- struct - Value type.

Reading:

- [Article about passing variables in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14686/C-Parameter-Pass-object-by-value-The-copy-construc)
- Wikipedia about [Objects copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy)- shallow copy + deep copy.

Quoting [Jon Skeet C# in depth second edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182471):

> **MYTH #3: “OBJECTS ARE PASSED BY REFERENCE IN C# BY DEFAULT”**
>
> This is probably the most widely propagated myth. Again, the people who make this
> claim often (though not always) know how C# actually behaves, but they don’t know
> what “pass by reference” really means. Unfortunately, this is confusing for people who
> do know what it means. The formal definition of pass by reference is relatively complicated,
> involving l-values and similar computer science terminology, but the important
> thing is that if you pass a variable by reference, the method you’re calling can change
> the value of the caller’s variable by changing its parameter value. Now remember that the
> value of a reference type variable is the reference, not the object itself. You can change
> the contents of the object that a parameter refers to without the parameter itself being
> passed by reference.
> For instance, the following method changes the contents of the
> **StringBuilder** object in question, but the caller’s expression will still refer to the
> same object as before:

```
void AppendHello(StringBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Append("hello");
}
```

> When this method is called, the parameter value (a reference to a StringBuilder) is
> passed by value. If I were to change the value of the builder variable within the
> method—for example, with the statement **builder = null;—that change wouldn’t be
> seen by the caller, contrary to the myth**.

*C# in depth Value types and reference types page 46*

Comment: @ghiboz. Another thing, make sure you make a [deep clone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) if that's what you need.

Comment: thanks for the link, so, definetively, if I use a class, if I write `private void testClass(cTest test)` or `private void testClass(ref cTest test)` is the same thing..

Comment: @ghiboz: if pass param with ref, you can use s.t like: test = new cTest(), and the param will be a new object, while if pass withou ref, test will be un-change if you assign: test = new cTest();

Comment: @ghiboz: if so, please investigate on how the compiler store the variable( primitive data type vs object data type, stack memory vs heap memory). You may discover the answer yourself

Answer (score 4):

If you want something like that, you want to use struts instead of classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make sure that a method can't modify an argument, then you can create a read-only base class:

```
public abstract class ReadOnlyUser
{
    public string GetName() { ... }
}

public class User : ReadOnlyUser
{
    public void SetName(string name) { ... }
}
```

Then you can write the method in such a way that the method body can't modify the argument by mistake:

```
public void Register(ReadOnlyUser user)
{
    string name = user.GetName();
    user.SetName("John"); // doesn't compile
}
```

Of course you can invoke this method with an instance of the `User` class:

```
var user = new User(...);
Register(user);
```

You can also implement a read-only interface:

```
public interface IReadOnlyUser
{
    string GetName();
}

public interface IUser : IReadOnlyUser
{
    void SetName(string name);
}

public class User : IUser
{
    public string GetName() { ... }
    public void SetName(string name) { ... }
}

public void Register(IReadOnlyUser user)
{
    string name = user.GetName();
    user.SetName("John"); // doesn't compile
}
```